# How could a raspberry find its local timezone without knowing latitude/longitude

Tags: raspberry-pi, timezone

Is there any way to let raspberry itself find its own **timezone** after it gets connected to WiFi, but without help of longitude and latitude because it doesn't have any GPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to first find some way to get a location for the device.

- If you have GPS, obviously use that.
- If you have Wi-Fi, then you might consider leveraging a [Wi-Fi Positioning System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system) database or API.  Several [are listed here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system#Public_Wi-Fi_location_databases), including both commercial and free options.
- If you only have wired Internet connection, you might consider using an [IP Geolocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation_software) database, though understand there are many accuracy tradeoffs in doing so.

Once you have the location, you can refer to the list of options under [*How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824)

If you don't have location at all, and you can't find a way to infer it, then sorry - you're out of luck.  You'd have to gather the time zone through some other mechanism, such as through a user interface or manually set configuration file.

Comment: my original answer to this question that I can solve it with geocoder has been deleted by moderator. i don't know is there any taboo about sharing Youtube link or anything.

Comment: Your answer consisted of a single link to a YouTube video.  Link-only answers are highly discouraged here, as there's no guarantee that the external resource will be available in the future (ie, it could be deleted).  Instead, if you can provide a detailed answer that can stand alone, you can also add a link to the YouTube video or other external resources to support your answer.  My answer is an example of that - as even if all of those Wikipedia links are deleted, the "meat" of the answer is still intact.  Feel free to add your own answer using the geocoder library.

Comment: thanks! Bascally it can be easily solved by python-geocoder.

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder to get location and timezone once device connects to Wi-Fi

```
import geocoder

g = geocoder.ip('me')
timezone = g.geojson['features'][0]['properties']['raw']['timezone']
```